# Error page is appeared on clicking a button in headless browser in Ruby-Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, google-chrome-headless

I am automating process of Walmart shopping card from product selection till complete Checkout process. I am using headless chrome browser for that in Ruby Selenium. When I click on 'Checkout' button after adding product to Cart, it navigates me to 'Error page' and returns me page title, 'Walmart Omnivore' and checkout process fails however checkout flow is completed successfully when I do it by launching browser. Problem is only in the checkout in headless browser.

I am using

- Ruby 2.4.3
- Selenium Gem : selenium-webdriver-3.5.2
- Chrome version: Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is my code,

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class TestBrowserHeadless


  chromePath = "chromedriver.exe" #Chrome browser exe file path

   #    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = chromePath
  #   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, switches: ['--incognito']
  #   driver.manage.window.maximize

  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = chromePath
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--headless')

  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

  driver.get "https://www.walmart.com/"

    puts driver.title

    driver.save_screenshot("test1.png")

    sleep 5

    search_field = driver.find_element(:id, 'global-search-input')
    search_field.click
    search_field.send_keys("623649985")
    search_field.submit

    sleep 5
    driver.save_screenshot("test2.png")

    puts driver.title

    prod_name = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//img[@class='Tile-img']")
    prod_name.click

    sleep 5
    driver.save_screenshot("test3.png")
    puts driver.title


    puts "Adding item to Cart"
    button_addCart = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[text()='Add to Cart']")
    button_addCart.click
    sleep 3

    driver.save_screenshot("test4.png")
    puts driver.title

    checkout_Btn = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='Cart-PACModal-POSContainer']/descendant::button[text()='Check Out']")
    checkout_Btn.click

    driver.save_screenshot("test5.png")
    sleep 4
    driver.save_screenshot("test6.png")
    puts driver.title
    puts "success"

    end
```

**NOTE:: Also, I tried clicking Checkout button after login walmart user and found same result**

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using 'headless' gem of ruby. https://leonid.shevtsov.me/post/headless/